# How to combine 2 separate lists in excel and form a seperate list

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

I need to combine two sequences and form a final sequence as the combination of the two sequence. How do I do that? I am a newbee please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "two sequences" located in the same column, try to use Index+Aggregate function

In `F2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C$1:C$11)/ISNUMBER(C$1:C$11),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

[image]